# Managing Tree Structure with Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Loading a tree works well in EF 4.1, but what are some thoughts about managing a tree structure in EF 4.1? For example, let's say a user want to move a node or set of nodes to a different child or parent node. What is the best way to manage removing nodes and all the children?

**Update:**

I saw [this](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/28/manage-trees-with-entity-framework-part-ii/), but not sure if this still applies since it was written in 2009.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with EF - it is your logic. EF works still the same it has an entity (node) where relations are removed and another entity (a new node) where relations are added. EF has no knowledge about meaning of your data (tree structure).

Comment: I understand that, however, should I consider cascading deletes and updates on my mappings? What are some good approaches, while using EF, to do what I ask? I am not asking for EF to know anything about my data or structure. I am asking, since I am using EF, what are some good ideas regarding managing tree structures.